# How to save data using SignalR?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I would like to save data using SignalR. For example,

```
public void ReservationOpened(long contractId, string username)
{
    // Save the contractId somewhere, that we can access it later. Let's call it ListOfOpenedIds
    Clients.All.reservationOpened(contractId, username);
}

public void ReservationClosed(long contractId)
{
    // look in ListOfOpenIds for contractId, and then remove it.
    Clients.All.reservationClosed(contractId);
}
```

How can I accomplish this? I heard that using Session is not recommended using SignalR. So I guess I won't use Http.Current.Context.Session.

As for Database approach, I don't like the fact of using dbWrite/dbRead for every open/close.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this? If Database approach is the best way, where should I initialize the database connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can store this data in a static variable. It will have global scope and not be unique to each user, but if you use a dictionary, you can lookup user (session) data based on connection id.

I use a session manager singleton class, with two dictionaries mapping connection id to session data and username to session data. This allows me to identify connecting users by connection id and to find relevant connection id's when sending messages to specific users.

The "session data" class:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        ConnectionIDs = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> ConnectionIDs { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

The "session manager" class:

```
public class Lobby
{
    private Lobby()
    {
        playersByUsername = new Dictionary<string, Player>();
        playersByConnectionID = new Dictionary<string, Player>();
    }

    private static Lobby singleton;
    public static Lobby Get()
    {
        if (singleton == null)
            singleton = new Lobby();

        return singleton;
    }

    Dictionary<string, Player> playersByUsername;
    Dictionary<string, Player> playersByConnectionID;

    public Player GetPlayerByUsername(string username)
    {
        if (playersByUsername.ContainsKey(username))
            return playersByUsername[username];

        return null;
    }

    public Player GetPlayerByConnectionID(string connectionID)
    {
        if (playersByConnectionID.ContainsKey(connectionID))
            return playersByConnectionID[connectionID];

        return null;
    }

    public void NewPlayer(Player player)
    {
        playersByUsername.Add(player.username, player);
        foreach (string connectionID in player.ConnectionIDs)
            playersByConnectionID.Add(connectionID, player);
    }

    public void NewConnection(string username, string connectionID)
    {
        playersByConnectionID.Add(connectionID, playersByUsername[username]);
        playersByUsername[username].ConnectionIDs.Add(connectionID);
    }

}
```